# Confusion about abbreviating map

Tags: scala

I would have thought the following code:

```
val a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(a.map(n => "x"))
```

Could be abbreviated to:

```
val a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(a.map("x"))
```

But the latter gives me the exception below. Why is this?

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   1 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of
>   range: 1  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.apply(StringLike.scala:52)
>     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString.apply(WrappedString.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString.apply(WrappedString.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.map(ArrayOps.scala:234)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Strings` are also functions `Int => Char` which fetches the char at the given index into the string. Therefore

```
a.map("x")
```

is equivalent to

```
a.map(i => "x".charAt(i))
```

The first element of `a` is `1` so this will try to find the char at index 1 in the string `x` which is out of range, hence the exception.

If you want a function that always returns `"x"` then you can use `Function.const`:

```
import Function.const
a.map(const("x"))
```

Comment: Or you can also do `a.map(_ => "x")`. It's kind of like the debate between whether to use `identity` or  `x => x`.

Answer (score 3):

In scala `String` is just a placeholder type for `java.lang.Strings`.

All instances of `String` are implicitly converted to `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps` which extends trait `StringLike[ String ]` which in-turn extends trait `IndexedSeqOptimized[Char, String]`.

Now, trait `IndexedSeqOptimized[Char, String]` defines an abstract apply method  `apply(index: Int): Char` which is implemented by trait `StringLike[ String ]`.

Hence each String instance like `val s = "A String"` can be used as a function of type `Int => Char` like this - `val c = s( 0 )`.

Now, your `a.map( "x" )` is equivalent to `a.map( i => "x".apply( i ) )` or `a.map( "x".apply( _ ) )` or `a.map( i => ( "x" )( i ) )` or simply `a.map( "x".apply )`.